# where did yum install my ruby executable?

Tags: rhel, ruby

I'm trying to install a modern Ruby on Amazon Linux which I think is RHEL based. I ran `sudo yum install rh-ruby26` which is a legit package, and it installed some files. However when I try and run ruby, there's no executable found.

I tried `rpm -ql rh-ruby26` but it says "contains no files".

Am I missing something ? Where did yum install my binary to run ruby ?

Comment: Did that get installed from Red Hat's SCL repository?

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104055/how-to-list-the-contents-of-a-package-using-yum] or [https://serverfault.com/questions/96964/list-of-files-installed-from-apt-package].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try under /opt/rh/rh-ruby26 and include that into your default path